# CSS display:inherit in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Supposedly IE9 supports the display:inherit properly, but apparently it doesn't apply display from an inline parent element such as a span tag to a block element such as a div, unless the display property is explicitly defined.  I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/LGre9/5/

Compare the difference in IE9 and Chrome or Firefox.  If I inspect the elements in IE9 I can see that IE9 thinks it's applying 'inline', but clearly it isn't.  This looks like an IE9 bug.  Unfortunately in the problem that I'm trying to fix, specifying display:inline explicitly on these elements is not a viable solution.  Is there something I have overlooked or something I can do to get the browser to behave like the other browsers?

Comment: can you explicitly apply `inline` to the span, because IE9 does respond to the `inherit` style then.  Or is that also not an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This looks like an IE9 bug.

I agree.

> Unfortunately in the problem that I'm trying to fix, specifying
>   display:inline explicitly on these elements is not a viable solution.

Adding `span { display: inline }` at the start of your stylesheet solves the problem, and I can't see why adding that is not a viable solution. It makes no difference whatsoever in any other browser.

Comment: This works, and will work for me as well.  I am working on a project with a very large codebase where I wasn't sure if I would be able to make changes to the right place, but it turns out that I can.